# CSS - display two text blocks on the same line

Tags: html, css, alignment

How can I position two text blocks on the same line, one to the left and the one to the right, without using floats?

Like this:

```
Bla bla                   5
Whatever                 25
Boo                      12
```

Each line is a list item - `<LI>`

Comment: Without using floats? You can use a table :)  If they're all inline elements, setting their `display:inline;` property should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use tables.
Also, you could use absolute positioning and setting the same value for top and bottom to each ul object

Answer (score 8):

You have numbers in your example, which indicates to me that you may be showing tabular data.  If that's the case, use a table.  Easy!

If that's not the case, use `span`s with a set width:

```
.label {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 200px; // or whatever
}
```

and:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="label">Blah blah</span>
        5
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="label">Stuff</span>
        25
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah, that's right.  I don't think it can be done without floats, then.  I just checked my site's code on something similar, and we depend on `inline-block` and just degraded to something else for IE6/7.

Comment: @zurahn - "IE 6/7 accepts the value only on elements with a natural display: inline"... span is an inline element, and therefore setting inline-block works just fine in IE

Comment: you are right though, setting inline-block on a div for example has undesirable results since it's natually a block-level element

Comment: I think you have a type in the answer. Shouldn't it be
`display: inline-block;`?

Answer (score 1):

you can see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mFRTz/)

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
li span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
}

<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Bla Bla</span>
        <span>5</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Whatever</span>
        <span>25</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old one, but it would seem like the most semantically correct option here would be to use DL, DT and DT instead of LI.

```
<dl>
<dt>Bla bla</dt><dd>5</dd>
<dt>Whatever</dt></dd>25</dd>
<dt>Boo</dt><dl>12</dl>
</dl>
```

Then you would style it like this:

```
dl {
    margin: 0;
}

dt {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
}
```

I know you stipulated no floats, but that is the way to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple trick I used. It does use `float`s, but I think it still looks pretty nice:

HTML:

```
<h1 class="title1">Chicken Craft</h1>
<h1 class="title2">Minecraft Server</h1>
```

CSS:

```
.title1 {
  text-align: left;
  color: #269CEB;
  margin-top: 0px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.title2 {
  text-align: left;
  color: #FF9D00;
}
```